# Setting up vscode for remote pylance

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using vscode with pylance on code that's remote, are the paths specified in the vscode configuration local machine paths or remote machine paths? When I specify library paths that I expect to exist on the remote machine in the local machine's vscode setup pylance still doesn't seem to find them.

Comment: It appears the problem was that pylance/vscode doesn't process tilde, so paths like ~/.venv/lib don't resolve. When changed to the full path it maps to the directory on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"python.languageServer": "Pylance"` to your .vscode/settings.json file. Doing that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a silly mistake: Also make sure to select the right python interpreter (on the bottom right). This is also the interpreter that Pylance will use.

Vscode defaulted to Python 2.7 for my Python 3.x project. So naturally Pylance struggled with some Python 3.x modules.